# Trouble with setting user input as semaphore variable

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to make a web scraping tool that is multithreaded, I'm using a [Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects) to limit the amount of threads that the program uses. I'm trying to assign a user input as the maximum number of threads but the program just stalls indefinitely.

```
import requests as r
import tkinter
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import threading
import time

threads = []
maxconnections = int(input("How many threads would you like: "))

sema = threading.BoundedSemaphore(value = maxconnections)

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
with open(filename, "r+", errors = "ignore", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
    contents = file.readlines()
    length = len(contents)
```

I believe that it's stalling before the Tk().withdraw() line as the dialogue box isn't opening for me, if I replace the input with a constant number the code works normally. Anybody know what the reason is?

```
maxconnections = 5
>>> Code works normally
```

Comment: Have you tried `root = Tk(); root.withdraw()` and at the end `root.destroy()`

Comment: @CoolCloud Yeah I've done that, just not sure why the variable is breaking on me